Why is it that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\varphi(x)-\varphi(-x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(x)dx$?
I tried using a change of variable but I don't seem to come up with the correct answer. $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\varphi(x)-\varphi(-x)dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\varphi(x)dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}\varphi(-x)dx$$ Defining $y=-x$, we get $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\varphi(x)dx+\int_{0}^{-\infty}\varphi(y)dy=\int_{0}^{\infty}\varphi(x)dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}\varphi(y)dy$$ I don't know what I am doing wrong.

$\int_{0}^{-\infty} = -\int_{-\infty}^0 \neq -\int_0^\infty$

Anyways, yes, $\int_0^\infty \varphi(x)-\varphi(-x),dx\ne \int_{-\infty}^\infty\varphi(x),dx$, because $$\int_0^\infty \varphi(x)-\varphi(-x),dx=\int_0^\infty\varphi(x),dx-\int_{-\infty}^0\varphi(x),dx.$$ See for instance the case $\varphi(x)=(1+x^2)^{-1}$.

Yes, but $\int_{0}^{\infty}\varphi(x)dx-\int_{-\infty}^{0}\varphi(y)dy\neq\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(x)dx$

Maybe there is a typo in the question.

@HornyPigeon54 -- $\varphi(x)$ is not Euler's totient function, I surmise. Otherwise, what then would be $\varphi(-x)$ exatly?

There should be the sum of the integrals, not the difference.
